# How can deploy project with local gitlab runner to local minikube?

Tags: continuous-integration, virtual-machine, gitlab-ci-runner, minikube

I have a local gitlab runner and minikube. I created gitlab-ci.yml to build and deploy a project to minikube. I know that both minikube and a gilab runner run on a virtual machine. If I use docker executor in gitlab runner, how can I connect from the container that runs the deploy job to the local minikube?
I don't care so much about a particular config file, at first, I want to know the idea behind this scene. Thanks.

Comment: A gitlab runner doesnt need to run on a VM. Just install the gitlab runner on the same host as minikube and use shell executor instead of docker executor

Comment: Thanks, but I am just curious about the thing that I questioned because I do it for learning. Whether is it possible?